# insert data through checkbox in laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I am trying to insert the checkbox data in database in which data are coming dynamically from database, 
Here is the form :

```
<form action="{{ $action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf()
                                @if(!empty($method)) @method($method) @endif
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">   
                                    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="{{ $u->id }}"></td>
                                        <td>{{ $u->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ trim($evtitle) }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ trim($evteacher) }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </table>
                                <input type="text" name="question_id[]" value="{{ trim($evid) }}">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Share" name="btn_btn_add_product">
                            </form>
```

Here is the controller :

```
$rs = ShareQuestion::create([
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
            'question_id' => $request->input('question_id')
        ]); 

        if($rs)
        {
          $message = array('flag'=>'alert-success', 'message'=>'Successfully');
          return redirect()->route('auth.question.index')->with(['message'=>$message]);
        }

        $message = array('flag'=>'alert-danger', 'message'=>'Please try again');
        return redirect()->route('auth.question.share')->with(['message'=>$message]);
```

Please help me out,

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the issue as your checkbox is not checked so data is not passed to the controller function.

so change from(if you want to send all user_id)

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="{{ $u->id }}"></td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" checked value="{{ $u->id }}"></td>
```

or you can pass the condition for a checked attribute by

```
{{ Form::checkbox('user_id[]',$u->id,true, array('class'=>'some_class')) }}
```

Comment: I hope the solution is working for you. Or tell us if you face any issue so at least we know where we are.

Answer (score 0):

**$request->user_id** and **$request->question_id**, array of values you have to use **json_encode()** method

```
$rs = ShareQuestion::create([
            'user_id' => json_encode($request->user_id),
            'question_id' => json_encode($request->question_id)
        ]);
```